# Почему gcc10 не видит флаг -fcoroutines?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

Я пытаюсь скомпилить таргет, с подключенным в него заголовком `#include <coroutine>`. Я подключил в cmake все необходимое.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
    project(cortest1)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
    
    add_executable(cortest1 main.cpp)
```

Но в ответ на мои попытки gcc10 вывод ошибку

> In file included from /home/anton/dev/cortest1/main.cpp:2:
> /usr/include/c++/10/coroutine:295:2: error: #error "the coroutine
> header requires -fcoroutines"   295 | #error "the coroutine header
> requires -fcoroutines"

Как это исправить?
Используется g++ версии  10.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте подумаем, а что делает команда SET ? она выставляет значение заданной переменной.

а что произойдет, если для одной и той же переменной будет вызвана дважды? где то так

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
```

второй вызов перетрет первый и компилятор не узнает о том, что нужны корутины. И будет жаловаться.

Что же делать? Можно поступить по Вашему и просто сделать вот так

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines -pthread")
```

и это будет в данном случае работать. Но давайте сделаем все красиво (тут я полагаю, что cmake старше третьей версии).

У меня получилось так

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(cortest1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
# добавим опцию компилятора, позволив, cmake самому разобраться с ней
add_compile_options(-fcoroutines)

add_executable(cortest1 main.cpp)

# а эти три строки включат поддержку pthread подключат ее куда нужно.
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(cortest1 PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```